Unit test error on check the try-with-resources block
The unit test should check some things related to try-with-resources in the class, viz:

No try without resources must be used
try-with-resources must be used to work with IO
Found usages of IO streams outside of try-with-resources

Maybe someone knows spoonAPI and can tell me in which area the error occurs?
Unit test:
@DisplayName("Test for non-functional requirements")
public class ComplianceTest {
    private static final Set<String> ALLOWED_PACKAGES = Set.of(
            "java.lang",
            "java.util",
            "java.io",
            "java.time",
            "java.time.format",
            "edu.epam.fop.io"
    );

    private static final Set<Class<?>> ALLOWED_CLASSES = Set.of(
            File.class,
            IOException.class,
            FileWriter.class,
            FileReader.class,
            BufferedWriter.class,
            BufferedReader.class
    );

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "varargs"})
    void shouldUseTryWithResources() {
        var spoon = new Launcher();
        spoon.addInputResource("src/main/java");
        spoon.buildModel();
        var factory = spoon.getFactory();
        var model = spoon.getModel();

        assertTrue(model
                .getElements(new CompositeFilter<>(FilteringOperator.SUBSTRACTION,
                        new TypeFilter<>(CtTry.class),
                        new TypeFilter<>(CtTryWithResource.class)))
                .isEmpty(), "No try without resources must be used");

        assertFalse(model
                .getElements(new TypeFilter<>(CtTryWithResource.class))
                .isEmpty(), "try-with-resources must be used to work with IO");

        var invalidRefs = model.getElements(new CompositeFilter<>(FilteringOperator.INTERSECTION,
                        new TypeFilter<>(CtTypeReference.class),
                        ref -> !ref.isPrimitive() && ref.getTypeDeclaration() != null,
                        ref -> ref.isSubtypeOf(factory.Class().createReference(AutoCloseable.class)),
                        ref -> ref.getPackage().equals(factory.Package().createReference("java.io"))
                )).stream()
                .filter(ref -> ref.getParent(el -> el.getRoleInParent() == CtRole.TRY_RESOURCE) == null)
                .toList();
        if (invalidRefs.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(invalidRefs);
        var msg = invalidRefs.stream()
                .filter(ref -> ref.getPackage().isImplicit())
                .map(this::toErrorCodeReference)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n".repeat(3)));

        throw new AssertionError("Found usages of IO streams outside of try-with-resources:\n" + msg);
    }

    private String toErrorCodeReference(CtElement element) {
        var pos = element.getPosition();
        return String.format("%s.java:%d", pos.getCompilationUnit().getMainType().getQualifiedName(), pos.getLine());
    }

And the file in which the check is being run:
public class LicenseReader {
    public void collectLicenses(File root, File outputFile) throws IOException {
        if (root == null || outputFile == null
                || outputFile.getName().isEmpty() || root.getName().isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        else if (!root.isDirectory() && !root.isFile()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        
        List<File> fileList = getFilesList(root);
        StringBuilder goodLicense = new StringBuilder();
        for (File file : fileList) {
            if (isValidHeader(file)) {
                goodLicense.append(getLicense(file)).append("\n");
            }
        }
        goodLicense.deleteCharAt(goodLicense.length() - 1);
        
        try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(goodLicense)); **/* If you remove this line, the test will pass, or vice versa, if you add more operations with bufferedWriter here, the invalidRefs list will increase*/**

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    private String[] getHeader(File file) {
        String[] header = new String[6];

        try (final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            int i = 0;
            String str;
            while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { **/*It's the same here*/**
                header[i++] = str;
                if (i == 6) break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return header;
    }

I tried to tinker with the filter for invalidRefs, but nothing worked.
It turns out that what is outside the round brackets try( *BRACKETS* ){...} the test starts to complain. And it should complain if it is called or actions occur outside the entire try block.
Either I don't understand, or the test is wrong.

Can you [edit] the question and make it a [mcve] (focus on the minimal part) please? Include the imports, reduce the code under test to the bare minimum, don't try to test 3 different things, only 1.

Seems appropriate to open an issue on the issue tracker: https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/issues/
